# How many nested structures can a programmer write in c++?

Tags: c++, struct

A programmer can write a 3 or more nested for loops.

My question is can I do the same with structures ?? 
I have seen a structure within a structure but can I write a structure within a structure which is within another structure ??

Comment: Sure you can.  Do you actually have a use case to do so?

Comment: I was just curious.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as many as the compiler supports, I would expect 1024 levels or even more.

It is a different question if it makes any sense; aside from idle curiosity, there is no reason to go multiple levels, it just shows poor style.

Answer (score 0):

The standard lists *recommendations* in Annex B.

> Because computers are finite, C++ implementations are inevitably limited in the size of the programs
>   they can successfully process. Every implementation shall document those limitations where known. This
>   documentation may cite fixed limits where they exist, say how to compute variable limits as a function of
>   available resources, or say that fixed limits do not exist or are unknown.
>
> The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or others. The bracketed number
>   following each quantity is recommended as the minimum for that quantity. However, these quantities are
>   only guidelines and do not determine compliance.

...

> (2.23) — Levels of nested class definitions in a single member-specification [256].

---

Seems like high enough. I cannot remember ever going over 2.